# Making my excel formatting python script more efficient

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

###Im trying to create a program that checks a column in excel and moves specific rows with specific values to another sheet in the same workbook, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this using pandas or something else.###

```
import time
start_time = time.perf_counter ()
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Test.xlsx")
ws=wb.active
mr,mc=ws.max_row,ws.max_column
column_string=input("Enter Column Letter with Email (A or B or C or leave blank to skip editing):").upper()
if len(column_string)>0:
    for cell in ws[column_string][1:]:
        if cell.value is None:
            ws_1=wb.create_sheet('Linkedin Only')
            for i in range (1, mr +1):
                for j in range (1, mc + 1):
                    c = ws.cell(row = i, column = j)
                    ws_1.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
            break
    for cell in ws_1[column_string][1:]:
        if cell.value is not None:
            ws_1.delete_rows(cell.row)
    for cell in ws[column_string][1:]:
        if cell.value is None:
            ws.delete_rows(cell.row)
    wb.save("Test.xlsx")
else:
    wb.save("Test.xlsx")
end_time = time.perf_counter ()
print(end_time - start_time, "seconds")
```

Comment: I don't think you need Pandas to make this more efficient, just follow the openpyxl documentation a bit more closely.

Comment: in which parts do u think I should be following openpyxl better? @CharlieClark